# How to modify this PyQt5 current setup to enable drag resize between layouts

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

How to modify this current setup to enable resizing(horizontally and vertically) between the layouts shown below? Let's say I want to resize the lists in the right toward the left by dragging them using the mouse, I want the image to shrink and the lists to expand and same applies for in between the 2 lists.

[image: window]

**Here's the code:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QDesktopWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QWidget,
                             QLabel, QListWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys


class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, left_ratio, right_ratio, window_title):
        super().__init__()
        self.left_ratio = left_ratio
        self.right_ratio = right_ratio
        self.current_image = None
        self.window_title = window_title
        self.setWindowTitle(self.window_title)
        win_rectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        center_point = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        win_rectangle.moveCenter(center_point)
        self.move(win_rectangle.topLeft())
        self.tools = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        self.left_widgets = {'Image': QLabel()}
        self.right_widgets = {'List1t': QLabel('List1'), 'List1l': QListWidget(),
                              'List2t': QLabel('List2'), 'List2l': QListWidget()}
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.left_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.right_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.adjust_widgets()
        self.adjust_layouts()
        self.show()

    def adjust_layouts(self):
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.left_layout, self.left_ratio)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.right_layout, self.right_ratio)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def adjust_widgets(self):
        self.left_layout.addWidget(self.left_widgets['Image'])
        self.left_widgets['Image'].setPixmap(QPixmap('test.jpg').scaled(500, 400, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,
                                                                        Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        for widget in self.right_widgets.values():
            self.right_layout.addWidget(widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test_window = TestWindow(6, 4, 'Test')
    sys.exit(test.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to rescale the image to an arbitrary size while maintaining its aspect ratio is to subclass `QWidget` and override `sizeHint` and `paintEvent` and use that instead of a `QLabel` for displaying the image, e.g.

```
class PixmapWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self._pixmap = None

    def sizeHint(self):
        if self._pixmap:
            return self._pixmap.size()
        else:
            return QSize()

    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        self._pixmap = pixmap
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        super().paintEvent(event)
        if self._pixmap:
            size = self._pixmap.size().scaled(self.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
            offset = (self.size() - size)/2
            rect = QRect(offset.width(), offset.height(), size.width(), size.height())
            painter.drawPixmap(rect, self._pixmap)
```

Since you are subclassing `QMainWindow` you could use `DockWidget`s to display the lists instead of adding them to the layout of the central widget, e.g.

```
class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, left_ratio, right_ratio, window_title):
        super().__init__()
        #self.left_ratio = left_ratio    <--- not needed since image and lists
        #self.right_ratio = right_ratio  <--- are not sharing a layout anymore

        ...

        # use PixmapWidget instead of QLabel for showing image
        # refactor dictionary for storing lists to make adding DockWidgets easier
        self.left_widgets = {'Image': PixmapWidget()}
        self.right_widgets = {'List1': QListWidget(),
                              'List2': QListWidget()}
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        # self.main_layout = QHBoxLayout()  <-- not needed anymore
        self.left_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.adjust_widgets()
        self.adjust_layouts()
        self.show()

    def adjust_layouts(self):
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.left_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def adjust_widgets(self):
        self.left_layout.addWidget(self.left_widgets['Image'])
        self.left_widgets['Image'].setPixmap(QPixmap('test.jpg').scaled(500, 400, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))

        self.dock_widgets = []
        for text, widget in self.right_widgets.items():
            dock_widget = QDockWidget(text)
            dock_widget.setFeatures(QDockWidget.NoDockWidgetFeatures)
            dock_widget.setWidget(widget)
            self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock_widget)
            self.dock_widgets.append(dock_widget)
```

**Screenshots**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html).

It acts almost like a box layout, but has handles that allow the resizing of each item.

Be aware that you can only add widgets to a QSplitter, not layouts, so if you need to add a "section" (a label and a widget) that can resize its contents, you'll have to create a *container* widget with its own layout.

Also note that using dictionaries for these kind of things is highly discouraged. For versions of Python older than 3.7, dictionary order is completely arbitrary, and while sometimes it *might* be consistent (for example, when keys are integers), it usually isn't: with your code some times the labels were put all together, sometimes the widgets were inverted, etc., so if somebody is using your program with <=3.6 your interface won't be consistent. Consider that, while python 3.6 will reach end of life in 2022, it's possible that even after that a lot of people will still be using previous versions.
If you need a way to group objects, it's better to use a list or a tuple, as I did in the following example.

If you *really* *"need"* to use a key based group, then you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), but it's most likely that there's just something wrong with the logic behind that need to begin with.

```
class TestWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, left_ratio, right_ratio, window_title):
        super().__init__()
        self.left_ratio = left_ratio
        self.right_ratio = right_ratio
        self.current_image = None
        self.window_title = window_title
        self.setWindowTitle(self.window_title)
        win_rectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        center_point = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        win_rectangle.moveCenter(center_point)
        self.move(win_rectangle.topLeft())
        self.tools = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        self.left_widgets = {'Image': QLabel()}
        self.right_widgets = [(QLabel('List1'), QListWidget()),
                              (QLabel('List2'), QListWidget())]
        self.central_widget = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.right_splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical, self)
        self.adjust_widgets()
        self.central_widget.setStretchFactor(0, left_ratio)
        self.central_widget.setStretchFactor(1, right_ratio)
        self.show()

    def adjust_widgets(self):
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.left_widgets['Image'])
        self.left_widgets['Image'].setPixmap(QPixmap('test.jpg').scaled(500, 400, Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,
                                                                        Qt.SmoothTransformation))
        self.left_widgets['Image'].setScaledContents(True)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.right_splitter)
        for label, widget in self.right_widgets:
            container = QWidget()
            layout = QVBoxLayout(container)
            layout.addWidget(label)
            layout.addWidget(widget)
            self.right_splitter.addWidget(container)
```

Comment: from Python 3.7 onward the ordering of items in a dictionary is not arbitrary but determined by the order in which the items were added.

Comment: @Heike thanks, I missed that. I'll fix the answer. Since <3.7 is still supported until the end of 2021, I think it's safe to write that using dictionaries is discouraged.