# How to make resizing of QLabels with QPixmaps responsive after adding/removing multiple images next to each other?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qpixmap

Can you help me make a responsive resize event when adding multiple QLabels integrated with QPixmaps? The labels/pixmaps doesn't resize when adding/removing them next to each other. I need to add +8 images next to each other, so in order to make the code minimal, the images are added in a unified definition controlled with QPushButtons. However, I would like the images to expand/shrink, according to available space in the window. I have attached sample code below. Thanks!

```
import os
import sys
os.chdir('C:/Ergolab/Motioncatch-Git/Ergolab/StackOverflow')

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainter

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(1200, 800)
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout()  

        self.btn_1 = QPushButton('First image')
        self.btn_1.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn_1.clicked.connect(self.plot_image)
        self.btn_1.setObjectName('1') # Used for object ID
        self.lbl_1 = QLabel()
        self.lbl_1.setMinimumSize(1, 1)

        self.btn_2 = QPushButton('Second image')
        self.btn_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn_2.clicked.connect(self.plot_image)
        self.btn_2.setObjectName('2') # Used for object ID        
        self.lbl_2 = QLabel()
        self.lbl_2.setMinimumSize(1, 1)

        self.btn_3 = QPushButton('Third image')
        self.btn_3.setCheckable(True)
        self.btn_3.clicked.connect(self.plot_image)
        self.btn_3.setObjectName('3') # Used for object ID     
        self.lbl_3 = QLabel()
        self.lbl_3.setMinimumSize(1, 1)

        self.horizontalLayoutButtons = QHBoxLayout()  
        self.horizontalLayoutButtons.addWidget(self.btn_1)
        self.horizontalLayoutButtons.addWidget(self.btn_2)
        self.horizontalLayoutButtons.addWidget(self.btn_3)

        self.horizontalLayoutImages = QHBoxLayout()  

        self.VerticalReportLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.VerticalReportLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayoutButtons)
        self.VerticalReportLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayoutImages)
        graph_widget = QWidget()
        graph_widget.setLayout(self.VerticalReportLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(graph_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.horizontalLayout)        


    def plot_image(self):

        # Find which image is checked:
        sending_button = self.sender()
        ActiveButton = str(sending_button.objectName())
        ButtonName = eval('self.btn_'+ActiveButton)
        self.LabelName = eval('self.lbl_'+ActiveButton)
        print(self.LabelName)

        if ButtonName.isChecked() == True:

            self.horizontalLayoutImages.addWidget(self.LabelName)
            self.pixmap = QPixmap('img_'+ActiveButton+'.png')
            self.LabelName.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        else:
            self.LabelName.clear()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486612/how-to-modify-this-pyqt5-current-setup-to-enable-drag-resize-between-layouts/60491226#60491226) help?

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much. If you post an answer I can accept it if you want to.

Comment: @FrederikPetri If the answer is in another post, it is unnecessary to write the same answer, you only have to mark it as a duplicate to your question.